# Grails hasMany with hasOne on the reverse side

Tags: grails, orm, relationship

I have a simple relationship between two tables as below:

```
class Book {
  String title
  static hasMany = [authors: Author]
}

class Author {
  String Name
}
```

I have a requirement that while Book can have many authors, one Author can only have one Book. Authors can exist independent of Books.

*With what constraints can I make sure that one Author can have one Book?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Book {
  String title
  static hasMany = [authors: Author]
}

class Author {
  String Name
  Book book  // this will be the belongTo relationship that you need

  static constraints = {
      book nullable:true
  }
}
```